# Pandas to_datetime produces impossible times

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timezone

I'm using pandas to convert strings into timestamps. I have a string as follows `'2016-03-12 18:09:19 PST'`.

If I do the following:

```
pd.to_datetime('2016-03-12 18:09:19 PST')
```

I get:

```
Timestamp('2016-03-13 02:09:19')
```

I'm not sure why this happens. Contrast to the behavior of:

```
pd.to_datetime('2016-03-12 18:09:19')
```

Which returns:

```
Timestamp('2016-03-12 18:09:19')
```

Note that the time `Timestamp('2016-03-13 02:09:19')` does not actually exist in US/Pacific time. If you try to do `pd.to_datetime('2016-03-12 18:09:19 PST').tz_localize('US/Pacific')` you will get a `NonExistentTimeError`.

Why does the introduction of "PST" at the end of the string induce the subtraction of 16 hours? How is it that `to_datetime` can introduce impossible dates?

Comment: It's not the subtraction of 16 hours, its the addition of 8 (note the date change). That would make it UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is converting your string to UTC time.  The issue is not present when "PST" is omitted because pandas assumes by default that the timestamp you provided is already in UTC, so it's not doing a conversion.

You can stop the conversion to UTC by using the `utc=False` keyword argument.

```
pd.to_datetime('2016-03-12 18:09:19 PST', utc=False)
```

Comment: I tried that `pd.to_datetime('2016-03-12 18:09:19 PST', utc=False)` returns `Timestamp('2016-03-13 02:09:19')`

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?  It returns `Timestamp('2016-03-12 18:09:19')` for me on pandas 0.17.0.

Comment: `pd.__version__` returns 0.17.1 so I suppose it could be a version issue. I'll update and see if it goes away.